# Fetch Disk space details of another server through Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program through which i can fetch the disk space utilisation details of one of our servers.
The program will execute from server A and will try to fetch disk space utilisation of server B. 
I tried to use Filesystem library of java but that gives me only current server details

Can anyone help me out here

Comment: So you want to know  how much space is used on the server?

Comment: Yes @SkrewEverything . I want to know how much space is left under var/vcap/store for Server B

Answer (score 0):

To know the size of a directory we can use `du -sh path_to_directory` command to get the size of directory.

You can use `ProcessBuilder` to execute the command.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command("bash","-c","du -s /var/vcap/store").start();
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
16G    /var/vcap/store
```

Above `16G` means the folder `store` takes `16G`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This will give me for the current server on which the java file is running. I want my code to fetch the disk details of another server 'A' while running on some other server 'B'

Comment: @RachitMGarg So what did you expect? There is no other "magical" way to get details of `"other machine"` from `"your machine"` without running a program on `"other machine"`. You can run this program on `"other machine"` and  save the output to a  file and send a HTTP request from `"your machine"` to `"other machine"` to get the data. YOU HAVE TO RUN THE COMMAND `du` for getting the information. Just write a bash script to run the command and send a HTTP request from `"your machine"` to receive the information.